# Comparar valores de matrizes e adicioná-los a outra (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Não estou conseguindo fazer a estrutura para comparar se o valor na posição[l][c] de uma matriz é maior que na mesma posição de outra, e se sim, esse valor vai para essa mesma posição em uma terceira matriz:

```
matrixOne = [[1, 12, 45], [58, 524, 78], [1, 2, 3], [45, 456, 8]]

matrixTwo = [[0, 1, 2], [85, 1, 74], [27, 63, 21], [25, 47, 962]]

matrixTrhee = [[], [], [], []]

for l in range(0, 4):

    for c in range(0, 4):

        if matrixOne[l][c] > matrixTwo[l][c]:

            matrixTrhee[l][c] = matrixOne[l][c]

        else:

            matrixTrhee[l][c] = matrixTwo[l][c]

for l in range(0, 4):

    for c in range(0, 4):

        print(f'[{matrixTrhee}{[l]}{[c]}:^5]', end=' ')

    print()
```

Comment: Importante sempre que postar uma pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Lembrando ainda que pode [edit] as postagens a qualquer momento para melhorar os detalhes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fazendo funcionar o código da pergunta:

```
matrixOne = [
[ 1,  12, 45], 
[58, 524, 78], 
[ 1,   2,  3],
[45, 456,  8]]

matrixTwo = [
[ 0,  1,  2], 
[85,  1,  74], 
[27, 63,  21], 
[25, 47, 962]]

#Inicializa a lista com todas as posições definidas
matrixTrhee = [[0,0,0] for _ in range(4)]

for l in range(0, 4):   
    #Aqui são três colunas e não quatro. 
    for c in range(0, 3):    
        if matrixOne[l][c] > matrixTwo[l][c]:    
            matrixTrhee[l][c]=matrixOne[l][c]    
        else:    
            matrixTrhee[l][c]=matrixTwo[l][c]

print(*matrixTrhee, sep="\n")
#[ 1,  12,  45]
#[85, 524,  78]
#[27,  63,  21]
#[45, 456, 962]
```

Uma alternativa mais compacta seria achatar(converter em vetor 1D) as matrizes e com o método da biblioteca padrão [itertools](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html), [`chain.from_iterable(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) e comparar os pares correspondentes de itens das matrizes.

O algoritmo é simples:

- Achata uma matriz e a [enumera](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) os elementos.
- Achata a outra matriz.
- Itere pela matriz enumeração e compare se aproveitando dos indices qual o [maior valor](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#max).
- Reagrupe o resultado na estrutura de matriz requerida.

Exemplo:

```
from itertools import chain

matrixOne = [
[ 1,  12, 45], 
[58, 524, 78], 
[ 1,   2,  3],
[45, 456,  8]]

matrixTwo = [
[ 0,  1,  2], 
[85,  1,  74], 
[27, 63,  21], 
[25, 47, 962]]


m1 = enumerate(chain.from_iterable(matrixOne))             #Achata e enumera matrixOne .
m2 = list(chain.from_iterable(matrixTwo))                  #Achata matrixTwo.
m3 = [max(v, m2[i]) for i, v in m1]                        #Itera por m1 e encontra o maior valor.

matrixTrhee= [m3[r: r+3] for r in range(0, len(m3), 3)]  #Reorganiza o resultado em uma matriz 4x3.

print(*matrixTrhee, sep="\n")
#[ 1,  12,  45]
#[85, 524,  78]
#[27,  63,  21]
#[45, 456, 962]
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/4Iu7mh)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Uma das forma válidas para resolver esta questão é:

```
matrixOne = [[1, 12, 45], [58, 524, 78], [1, 2, 3], [45, 456, 8]]
matrixTwo = [[0, 1, 2], [85, 1, 74], [27, 63, 21], [25, 47, 962]]

matrixTrhee = []
for l in range(4):
    line = []
    for c in range(3):
        if matrixOne[l][c] > matrixTwo[l][c]:
            line.append(matrixOne[l][c])
        else:
            line.append(matrixTwo[l][c])
    matrixTrhee.append(line)

print(matrixTrhee)
```

Observe que o primeiro bloco **for** percorre o **range(4)** - equivalente ao número de linhas da matriz **matrixTrhee**. Em seguida, o segundo bloco **for** percorre o **range(3)** - equivalente ao número dae colunas da matriz **matrixTrhee** - verificando se cada elemento da **matrixOne** é maior que o correspondente elemento da **matrixTwo**. Caso positivo, será adicionado em **line** o elemento **matrixOne[l][c]**. Caso contrário, o elemento **matrixTwo[l][c]** é adicionado em **line**.

Para cada encerramento do **2º bloco for** é adicionado **line** à **matrixTrhee**.

Finalizando as atividades dos dois blocos **for** é exibida a seguinte saída.

```
[[1, 12, 45], [85, 524, 78], [27, 63, 21], [45, 456, 962]]
```

---

Agora, se preferir exibir a matriz em forma tabular, pode utilizar a biblioteca numpy. Dessa forma o código ficará:

```
import numpy as np

matrixOne = [[1, 12, 45], [58, 524, 78], [1, 2, 3], [45, 456, 8]]
matrixTwo = [[0, 1, 2], [85, 1, 74], [27, 63, 21], [25, 47, 962]]

matrixTrhee = []
for l in range(4):
    line = []
    for c in range(3):
        if matrixOne[l][c] > matrixTwo[l][c]:
            line.append(matrixOne[l][c])
        else:
            line.append(matrixTwo[l][c])
    matrixTrhee.append(line)

print(np.array(matrixTrhee))
```

Depois de realizado todas as operações será exibida a seguinte saída:

```
[[  1  12  45]
 [ 85 524  78]
 [ 27  63  21]
 [ 45 456 962]]
```

---

Se preferir também podes utilizar **[List Comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)**. Desta forma o código ficará:

```
import numpy as np

matrixOne = [[1, 12, 45], [58, 524, 78], [1, 2, 3], [45, 456, 8]]
matrixTwo = [[0, 1, 2], [85, 1, 74], [27, 63, 21], [25, 47, 962]]

matrixTrhee = [[matrixOne[l][c] if matrixOne[l][c] > matrixTwo[l][c] else matrixTwo[l][c]
                for c in range(3)] for l in range(4)]

print(np.array(matrixTrhee))
```

Produzindo a seguinte saída:

```
[[  1  12  45]
 [ 85 524  78]
 [ 27  63  21]
 [ 45 456 962]]
```

---

Se não houver necessidade em exibir os delimitadores - [] - podemos utilizar **[Expressões Geradoras](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions)**. Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
matrixOne = [[1, 12, 45], [58, 524, 78], [1, 2, 3], [45, 456, 8]]
matrixTwo = [[0, 1, 2], [85, 1, 74], [27, 63, 21], [25, 47, 962]]

matrixTrhee = ((matrixOne[l][c] if matrixOne[l][c] > matrixTwo[l][c] else matrixTwo[l][c]
                for c in range(3)) for l in range(4))

for i in matrixTrhee:
    for j in i:
        print(f'{j:>5}', end='')
    print()
```

Obtendo a seguinte saída:

```
    1   12   45
   85  524   78
   27   63   21
   45  456  962
```

Ou, podemos simplesmente comparar os valores e exibir os resultados.

```
matrixOne = [[1, 12, 45], [58, 524, 78], [1, 2, 3], [45, 456, 8]]
matrixTwo = [[0, 1, 2], [85, 1, 74], [27, 63, 21], [25, 47, 962]]

print(f'A matrixTrhee é:')
for l in range(4):
    for c in range(3):
        if matrixOne[l][c] > matrixTwo[l][c]:
            print(f'{matrixOne[l][c]:>5}', end='')
        else:
            print(f'{matrixTwo[l][c]:>5}', end='')
    print()
```

Então, obtemos a seguinte saída:

```
A matrixTrhee é:
    1   12   45
   85  524   78
   27   63   21
   45  456  962
```